# Why is my Gitlab runner not detected? This job is stuck because you don't have any active runners online

Tags: gitlab

I have registered Gitlab runner

[image]

My job is pending in Gitlab CI

```
This job is stuck because you don't have any active runners online or available with any of these tags assigned to them: fluffa-docker
```

My gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy-stage

build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - fluffa-docker
```

Here is my tag

```
  image: docker:20-git
  services:
    - docker:20-dind
  script:
    - apk update && apk add jq
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$VERSION -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$VERSION
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest

deploy-stage:
  stage: deploy-stage
  image: alpine:latest
  script:
    - chmod og= $STAGE_ID_RSA
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -i $STAGE_ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $STAGE_SERVER_USER@$STAGE_SERVER_IP "docker stop $CI_PROJECT_NAME || true"
    - ssh -i $STAGE_ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $STAGE_SERVER_USER@$STAGE_SERVER_IP "docker rm $CI_PROJECT_NAME || true"
    - ssh -i $STAGE_ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $STAGE_SERVER_USER@$STAGE_SERVER_IP "docker image rm $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true"
    - ssh -i $STAGE_ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $STAGE_SERVER_USER@$STAGE_SERVER_IP "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY"
    - ssh -i $STAGE_ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $STAGE_SERVER_USER@$STAGE_SERVER_IP "docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"
    - ssh -i $STAGE_ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $STAGE_SERVER_USER@$STAGE_SERVER_IP "docker run -d --restart unless-stopped --name
```

I can not grasp how it can not find valid and running Gitlab runner.
Why is my runner not detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if the runner is not locked and shared or Specific assigned to the subjected repo/project? you check this by `opening your repo> settings > CICD> Runners`.  look for your runner and please share the result.
another way to check if you have admin privileges:  Admin Area > Overview > runners.

if locked open it  `Admin Area > Overview > runners > select your runner`  and uncheck `When a runner is locked, it cannot be assigned to other projects`

Answer (score 0):

Check this flag in your runner Edit:

```
Indicates whether this runner can pick jobs without tags
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to CI Settings-> Expand the runner option-> Click the edit option-> Tick mark the box that says 'Indicates whether this runner can pick jobs without tags'